# C++ Direct2D - Linker error 2019 after moving sine files from my laptop

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, directx

I wanted to move some code that I wrote, on my laptop, to my other PC. I didn't use Github or any other type of source control, I just simply copied the c++ files on to a USB drive and put them on my other PC.

And now I'm getting an error, for some reason, when I try to run the code?

The code is simply a class that uses direct2d to draw on a window.

This is what it looks like:

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "LinkedList.h"

class Graphics
{
private:
    ID2D1Factory* pFactory;
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* pRenderTarget;
    ID2D1SolidColorBrush* pBrush;

    RECT bounds;

    float lineWidth = 5.0f;
    LinkedList pointList;


public:
    Graphics();
    ~Graphics();

    void BeginDraw() { pRenderTarget->BeginDraw(); };
    void EndDraw() { pRenderTarget->EndDraw(); };


    void SetBrushColor(float r, float g, float b, float a);
    void SetBrushColor(float r, float g, float b);

    void SetLineWidth(float width);

    RECT GetBounds();

    void ClearScreen(float r, float g, float b, float a);
    void ClearScreen(float r, float g, float b);

    void FillCircle(float x, float y, float radius);
    void DrawCircle(float x, float y, float radius);

    void FillRect(float x, float y, float w, float h);
    void DrawRect(float x, float y, float w, float h);

    void MoveTo(float x, float y); 
    void LineTo(float x, float y); 

    void tester();

    bool Init(HWND* pWindowHandle);
};
```

And the error I'm getting is this:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _D2D1CreateFactory@16 referenced in function "long __cdecl D2D1CreateFactory(enum D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE,struct _GUID const &,void * *)" (?D2D1CreateFactory@@YAJW4D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE@@ABU_GUID@@PAPAX@Z)  ffff    c:\Users\sharkgaming\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ffff\ffff\Graphics.obj   1
```

At first I thought it was because I forgot to link to the d2d1.lib but even after doing that I'm still getting the error?

So, does anyone know why I'm getting the error and how to fix it?

Comment: open your `d2d1.lib` in any viewer (even in notepad) and search for `_D2D1CreateFactory@16` exactly (or for `__imp__D2D1CreateFactory@16`) - think you not found this string (linker can not found it) this mean you have old version of  `d2d1.lib` - so you need download and install latest SDK

Comment: Thanks, but I just checked my DirectX version and it said I had DirectX 11 so I don't think that's it :(

Comment: turns out its because visual studio is not linking to the d2d1.lib file even though i went in to the settings and added it to the additional library files..

Comment: the `d2d1.lib` absolute independent from   DirectX version - this is absolute different things. ok. but you say at begin that you have error even when link with `d2d1.lib` so i and assume that this is old lib, not containing `_D2D1CreateFactory@16`

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
after googling around, for an hour or two, I found out that basically adding this:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"d2d1.lib")
```

would fix my problem.

But I have absolutely no idea why, since I already went in to the linker settings and added d2d1.lib to the additional library files?

EDIT: OMG I just figured it out.
I added the library to the x64 build settings not the x86.  -_-